# Are there reliable algorithms for generating robust DOM node selectors, given only the target node?

Tags: dom, xpath, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

In writing a scraper, we typically use some kind of selector to identify particular nodes of interest.  Ideally the selectors should continue to work even as the page changes over time.  A lot of the common approaches like grabbing nodes by id are fragile on frequently updated pages and impossible on some nodes.  I'm trying to find good algorithms for generating robust selectors, but since there doesn't seem to be a standard terminology for this problem, it's hard to find everything that's out there.

Here are the selector DSLs I already know.

- XPath selectors - Implemented everywhere from JS to the popular
  Python and Ruby scraping libraries.
- CSS selectors - Found in many of the places where you can find xpath
  selectors.
- High level selectors - Here I'll give the example of Chickenfoot,
  which allows users to write `click("begin tutorial")` to find a link
  with the text "Begin Tutorial."  Usually these are implemented on top of
  xpath and CSS selectors.  I'd love to find out about more members of
  this language family.
- Visual selectors - This would be the approach taken by, for instance,
  Sikuli, which makes it appear as though the program is calling a
  function on a screengrab of the relevant node.  I don't know any
  web-specific instances of this approach, but I imagine there are
  some.

Here are the selector generation algorithms I already know.  By a selector generation algorithm I mean an algorithm that takes a node as input and produces a robust selector as output.

- iMacros: Finds all elements with the same node type and text as the
  target element, finds the target element's index in this list list.  Uses
  the node type, text, and index as the selector.  Also includes id
  for forms and form elements.
- CoScripter: Uses element's text if available.  If not, uses preceding
  text.
- Selenium: Uses id where available.  Uses various other attributes
  otherwise, such as image alt text, links' displayed texts, buttons'
  displayed texts.
- Wargo System: Uses element text.
- Many systems: Many systems use the xpath from the root to the target node, or some
  suffix of that xpath.

All of these selector generation algorithms fail on some nodes.  Are there better approaches out there?  Or other approaches that I could combine with these algorithms to produce a better hybrid algorithm?

Comment: Selectors and XPath are both tightly coupled with document tree structure. Aside from immutable IDs, there is little that can be done to ensure that you identify the correct element regardless of changes in document structure.

Comment: I certainly agree with you that there's no way to _ensure_ a correct answer, but I've also found empirically that some of the algorithms above work better than others.  I'm not looking for any guarantees, but I am looking for approaches that work well in general.

Answer (score 0):

When I started investigating this topic for some work I am doing, I was also surprised by how little information is available on this topic.

I did find this 2003 paper, but unfortunately, I only have access to the abstract:

[Abe, Mari, and Masahiro Hori. “Robust Pointing by XPath Language: Authoring Support and Empirical Evaluation.” In Proceedings of the 2003 Symposium on Applications and the Internet, 156 – . SAINT ’03. Washington, DC, USA: IEEE Computer Society, 2003.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=827273.829216)

For my own use, I followed the approach in [Tim Vasil's 50-line jquery plugin](http://www.timvasil.com/blog14/post/2014/02/24/Build-a-unique-selector-for-any-DOM-element-using-jQuery.aspx). I won't reproduce the code which is available at that link, but instead I'll describe it:

It recursively traverses up the DOM tree from the element, building a selector "backwards". At each level:

1. If the node has an ID, just use that and skip all the parents; they aren't added to the selector.
2. If node has a tag name or a set of classes that is unique among its siblings, use that as the selector. Otherwise, use :nth-child.

Since I will be storing element contents between visits to a page, I'm thinking of implementing some "blunder detection" here, maybe using a percentage change from last visit to detect if the selector may be grabbing the wrong element.